# Removing elements from a list in python3

Tags: python, list

Im having trouble getting started on this code and hoping I could get some help. I have a list called STATE_LIST which contains the abbreviations for all states in the U.S. What I need to do is print this list in a window and as the user enters one of the abbreviations from STATE_LIST in a text box I need to remove that abbreviation from the list printed in the window.Here is my entire code so far hope you guys can make sense of it. Thank You.

```
from proj2_support_code import *

def verify_input(x,y):
    for i in range (len(x)):
        if x[i] == y.upper():
            return True



def clicked_trump(x_point,y_point):


    trump_top_left_x = WINDOW_WIDTH * .25 - 50
    trump_top_left_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0
    width = 100
    height = 100
    trump_top_left = Point(trump_top_left_x, trump_top_left_y)
    trump_bottom_right = Point(trump_top_left_x + width, trump_top_left_y + height)


    if (trump_top_left.getX() <= x_point <= trump_bottom_right.getX() and trump_top_left.getY() <= y_point <=
       trump_bottom_right.getY()):
        return True

def clicked_clinton(x_point, y_point):

    clinton_top_left_x = WINDOW_WIDTH * .75 - 50
    clinton_top_left_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0
    width = 100
    height = 100
    clinton_top_left = Point(clinton_top_left_x, clinton_top_left_y)
    clinton_bottom_right= Point(clinton_top_left_x + width,clinton_top_left_y + height )

    if (clinton_top_left.getX() <= x_point <= clinton_bottom_right.getX() and clinton_top_left.getY() <= y_point <=
       clinton_bottom_right.getY()):
        return True


def main():

    win= GraphWin('Project_2',WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)

    clin_in_v = 0
    tru_in_v = 0



    trump_img = Image(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH*.25,WINDOW_HEIGHT/6 - 50),"trump.gif")  # Filenames of candidate pics
    trump_img.draw(win)

    clinton_img = Image(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH * .75,WINDOW_HEIGHT/6 -50),"clinton.gif")
    clinton_img.draw(win)

    textbox_trump = Text(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH * .245, WINDOW_HEIGHT/6 +10), "VOTES: " + str(clin_in_v))
    textbox_trump.draw(win)

    textbox_clinton = Text(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH * .75, WINDOW_HEIGHT/6 +10), "VOTES: " + str(tru_in_v))
    textbox_clinton.draw(win)


    inst_textbox = Text(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH * .5, WINDOW_HEIGHT - USER_INSTRUCTIONS_HEIGHT), "Enter a state abbreviation, then click a picture.")
    inst_textbox.draw(win)
    entrybox = Entry(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH * .5,WINDOW_HEIGHT - ENTRYBOX_HEIGHT), 10)
    entrybox.draw(win)

    STATE_LISTbox= Text(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH * .5, WINDOW_HEIGHT *.5),'States Remaining:' + str(STATE_LIST))
    STATE_LISTbox.draw(win)

    for i in range(len(STATE_LIST)):
        STATE_LISTB = print(STATE_LIST[i])

    STATE_LISTB.draw(win)

    clin_in_v1=0
    tru_in_v1 =0
    for i in range(50):
        c_point = win.getMouse()
        x_c_point = c_point.getX()
        y_c_point = c_point.getY()

        if clicked_trump(x_c_point,y_c_point) == True:
            enteredtext = entrybox.getText().upper()
            x= verify_input(STATE_LIST,enteredtext)
            if x == True:
                tru_in_v1 = STATE_VOTES[enteredtext] + tru_in_v
            else:
                print('Incorrect State Entered:',enteredtext)

            tru_in_v = tru_in_v1

            textbox_trump.setText("VOTES: " + str(tru_in_v))




        elif clicked_clinton(x_c_point, y_c_point) == True:
            enteredtext = entrybox.getText().upper()
            x = verify_input(STATE_LIST,enteredtext)
            if x == True:
                clin_in_v1 = STATE_VOTES[enteredtext] + clin_in_v
            else:
                 print('Incorrect State Entered:', enteredtext)

            clin_in_v = clin_in_v1

            textbox_clinton.setText("VOTES: " + str(clin_in_v))



    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

So the user enters a state abbreviation into the entrybox then clicks on an image of a presidential candidate. The votes are then added to the candidates total vote count. I need to place a list in the graphics window that lists all the state abbreviations and as the user enters a state abbreviation into the entrybox and clicks a candidate, that abbreviation needs to be removed from the state list.

Comment: Show your code attempt and explain what difficulties you have in your own code.

Comment: Should we assume that you have no code so far since you didn't post any?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add your code. And please add only the code required to reproduce the problem, not your "entire" code.

Comment: Sorry Im new to this side and python as well. Heres my entire code.

Answer (score 0):

When one index which was inputed from users is removed from the list, I think that it can be thought a following script.

```
list = ["AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF"]
idx = list.index("BC")
list.pop(idx)
print(list)
```

At 2nd line, a word inputed is serched.
At 3rd line, a word from list is removed.

if you don't want to breake the list, the 3rd line becomes as follows.

```
list[idx] = ""
```

Is this a hint for you?